# User account and Commerce addressfield bug

Tags: tokens, commerce

I found out that when I enter a "Full name" in the commerce shipping and billing address information, the [user:name] value will be changed to the "Full name" entered.

As you can see the user name in the first picture is different from the value of the [user:name] token.

[image]

[image]

However, when I enter a different "Full name" for subsequent orders, or change the username it doesn't modify the value of the [user:name] token.

Is there a way to stop the commerce shipping and billing to modify the [user:name] token or to change the value of the token manually?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer!

Go to profiles\commerce_kickstart\modules\commerce_kickstart\commerce_kickstart_user and comment out

```
function commerce_kickstart_user_username_alter(&$name, $account) {
  if (module_exists('commerce_addressbook')) {
    $billing_profile_id = commerce_addressbook_get_default_profile_id($account->uid, 'billing');
    if ($billing_profile_id) {
      $billing_profile = commerce_customer_profile_load($billing_profile_id);
      $name = $billing_profile->commerce_customer_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['name_line'];
    }
  }
}
```

and everything goes back to normal!

Answer (score 0):

I modified the user.tokens.inc file by changing $user['name'] to $user['login-name'] and commented out a line and this seemed to fix the problem of the tokens, as the token isn't modified by the username value in $account.

```
case 'login-name':
//$name = format_username($account);
$replacements[$original] = $sanitize ? check_plain($name) : $name;
break;
```

[image]

However, as you can see, I still haven't solved the problem of the the username field in $account is being modified by commerce shipping and billing. The result is the same whether I set the field to "Full name" or "First name" and "Last name". Inspecting the addressfield module, I can't find the part where it modifies the $account username.